# Problema ao realizar update

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

Tenho no site o sistema para cadastrar, listar e editar usuários.

Cadastrar e listar estão ok, porém, ao tentar atualizar um registro, o mesmo não é alterado no `DB` e também não retorna nenhum erro. Já chequei a conexão e está correta.

Seguem os códigos:

**listar.php**

```
<?php
include_once("conexao.php");

$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
while ($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)){
    echo $row_usuario['id_cli']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['nome_cli']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['cpf_cli']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['cnpj_cli']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['raz_cli']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['tel_cli']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['cel_cli']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['email_cli']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['senha_cli']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['nivel']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['ip_cli']."<br>";
    echo $row_usuario['data_cad_cli']."<br>"; ?>

<a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $row_usuario['id_cli']; ?>">Editar</a>
<hr>

<?php }
?>
```

**editar.php**

```
    <?php
include_once("conexao.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];
$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cli=$id";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
$row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
?>

<form method="post" action="processa_edicao.php">
<input name="id_cli" type="number" readonly id="id" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['id_cli'] ?>">
<input name="nome_cli" type="text" required="required" id="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['nome_cli'] ?>">
<input name="cpf_cli" type="number" required="required" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['cpf_cli'] ?>">
<input name="cnpj_cli" type="number" id="cnpj" placeholder="CNPJ" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['cnpj_cli'] ?>">
<input name="raz_cli" type="text" id="razao_social" placeholder="Razão Social" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['raz_cli'] ?>">
<input name="tel_cli" type="tel" id="telefone" placeholder="(99)9999-9999" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['tel_cli'] ?>">
<input name="cel_cli" type="tel" id="celular" placeholder="(99)99999-9999" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['cel_cli'] ?>">
<input name="email_cli" type="email" required="required" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['email_cli'] ?>">
<input name="senha_cli" type="text" required="required" id="senha" placeholder="Senha" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['senha_cli'] ?>">
<select name="nivel" required id="nivel">
  <option value="1">Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Básico</option>
  <option value="2">Profissional</option>

  <input name="ip_cli" type="number" readonly id="ip" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['ip_cli'] ?>">
  <input name="data_cad_cli" type="datetime" readonly id="data_cad" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['data_cad_cli'] ?>">

  <input type="submit" value="Editar">
</select>
</form>
```

**processa_edicao.php**

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['nome_cli'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf_cli'];
$cnpj = $_POST['cnpj_cli'];
$razao_social = $_POST['raz_cli'];
$telefone = $_POST['tel_cli'];
$celular = $_POST['cel_cli'];
$email = $_POST['email_cli'];
$senha = $_POST['senha_cli'];
$nivel_id = $_POST['nivel'];

$id = $_POST['id'];

include_once("conexao.php");

$result_usuario = "UPDATE clientes SET nome_cli = '$nome', cpf_cli = '$cpf', cnpj_cli = '$cnpj', raz_cli = '$razao_social', tel_cli = '$telefone', cel_cli = '$celular', email_cli = '$email', senha_cli = '$senha', nivel = '$nivel_id'  WHERE id_cli = '$id'";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

header("location: listar.php");
?>
```

**conexao.php**

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "cadastro_usuarios";

//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

if(!$conn){
    die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    //echo "Conexao realizada com sucesso";
}
?>
```

Comment: Existem alguns problemas e também possíveis melhorias em seu código, mas vamos partir do básico. Altera a linha "$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);" para "$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario) or die(mysqli_error($conn));", rode e poste aqui o resultado.

Comment: Uma dúvida: por que que, ao editar, você só altera o nome, mas armazena todas as variáveis recebidas no $_POST?

Comment: $result_usuario = "UPDATE clientes SET nome_cli = '$nome', cpf_cli = '$cpf', ........   WHERE id_cli = '$id'";

Comment: Solução na resposta editada

Comment: Você pode editar a sua pergunta com as alterações feitas?

Comment: Alterei a pergunta, Leo.

Answer (score 2):

1: Quando você manda fazer

`"UPDATE clientes SET nome_cli = '$nome' WHERE id_cli = '$id'";`

só está atualizando o nome.

Para atualizar todos os campos recebidos via post tem que ser assim:

```
$result_usuario = "UPDATE clientes SET nome_cli = '$nome', cpf_cli = '$cpf', cnpj_cli = '$cnpj', raz_cli = '$razao_social', tel_cli = '$telefone', cel_cli = '$celular', email_cli = '$email', senha_cli = '$senha', nivel = '$nivel_id'  WHERE id_cli = '$id'";
```

2: Na página editar.php no  `<input name="id_cli" type="number" disabled id="id"`

troque o **disabled** por **readonly**

> Disabled não passa o valor para o fomulário, além de não poder editar.
>
> Readonly envia o valor para o formulário e também não pode editar.

<sub>Se você criar um formulário em html e definir algum campo input com a propriedade disabled, saiba que ao realizar o submit o PHP não receberá esse valor!</sub>

<sub>É como se o campo/variável nem existisse! E isso vale para qualquer outro elemento de formulário que tenha definida a propriedade disabled em seu código.</sub>

Comment: Leo, seria legal se você pudesse complementar sua resposta, deixando claro para o usuário o motivo de não estar funcionando, o porque de fazer da forma que mencionou, etc... Dar a resposta "de mão beijada" para o usuário até resolve a questão, mas não agrega muito para a comunidade em sí.

Comment: Nossa, enquanto digitava você complementou. Ótimo!

Comment: Transmimento de pensação, rs

Comment: Leo eThiago. Eu não inseri todos os campos no UPDATE a fim de teste apenas. Mas fiz as alterações conforme me passaram mas não funcionou.

        $result_usuario = "UPDATE clientes SET nome_cli = '$nome', cpf_cli = '$cpf', cnpj_cli = '$cnpj', raz_cli = '$razao_social', tel_cli = '$telefone', cel_cli = '$celular', email_cli = '$email', senha_cli = '$senha', nivel = '$nivel_id'  WHERE id_cli = '$id'";
 $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

Comment: Leo. Fiz a alteração conforme você disse trocando **disable** por **readonly**. Mas ainda nada. Refiz todo o código novamente usando as suas informações e a do Thiago. Só que não houve mudança.

Comment: Leo. Refiz todo o processo alterando com as informações que me passou. Nada ainda. Será a versão?

Comment: Versão do que? PHP? minha versão é PHP Version 5.4.43

Comment: edita sua pergunta com os arquivos já modificados